# Select option not validating in jquery validation framework

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using jquery validation framework. I've a select tag in a carousel, where if it doesn't have any value it should not go to next slide. The select tag has the class "validate basic-required-options" before clicking on continue to next slide. When I click on continue, it goes to next slide by adding "valid" class which is not correct. I'm not able to get why its validating even though if I don't select anything. It should add "error" class by validating. Any suggestions?

My code

```
<select id="eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimBonusInBPS" 
    name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS"
    class="bb-search-action-dropdown selectpicker ">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="0" <@s.property value="%{form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS == 0 ? 'selected':''}"/>>1 year(0%)</option>
    <option value="20" <@s.property value="%{form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS == 20 ? 'selected':''}"/>>2 years(20%)</option>
</select>
```

This select tag has the class by adding it in JS.

Comment: reproduce the error in a fiddle and share it with us.

Comment: I feel very sorry to create a fiddle for it. :(